# How to prevent Joomla from changing tags inside <noscript>

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have added following code to my Joomla template index.php:

```
<noscript>
    <div></div>
    <link rel=stylesheet href="/media/style.css"/>
</noscript>
```

But Joomla changed it into:

```
<noscript>&lt;div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;link rel=stylesheet href="/media/style.css"/&gt;</noscript>
```

Which won't work because of missing angel brackets.

Code is inside , but putting it into body didn't help. Also creating a module returned same result.
I know that div tag doesn't make any sense. It is only for testing and removing it doesn't help.

Does anyone know, how to prevent Joomla from messing my noscript tags?
Thanks in advance for any advices!

Comment: By default, Joomla does not convert any HTML to it's respected entity in the template's `index.php` file. If this is happening, it's most likely a template helper file or a plugin doing so.

Comment: I have disabled all modules and all plugins with ID greater than 10000, then reduced my index.php (inside template) to:
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <noscript>
  <link rel=stylesheet href="/media/style.css"/>
 </noscript>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>`
But it returned same result. Are you sure, that it isn't basic Joomla action? I am using Joomla 3.6.5.

Comment: Have just tried to disable also plugins with ID below 10000 (so all modules and plugins disabled), but still no luck.

Comment: Where are you seeing `&lt;div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;`? On the actual page or when you open your browser inspector? Also, which template are you using?

Comment: It's Chrome bug. I have posted an answer. Thank you for help!

Comment: Oh wow, I wouldn't have guessed that. Nice find!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's bug in Chrome ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800526/how-do-i-display-html-within-chromes-noscript-tag)). Haven't encountered it before and that's why my first thought was that it's connected with Joomla. Sorry for my mistake!